# Qt error: cannot open output file debug

Tags: c++, qt

Today I was debuging my program and suddenly due to power failure, my pc shutdown abnormally. Now when I compile that program, it gives me two errors.

```
:-1: error: cannot open output file debug\Myprogram.exe: Invalid argument
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I cleaned the program, rebuilt it. Ran qmake. Closed the compiler and relaunched to compile program by first running qmake, then debugging but worthless. The program isn't getting compiled. I am a beginner and don't have much knowledge about these problems so bear this question. :). How can i fix it.

Comment: Manually delete everything in the debug (and temp) folders - don't trust the 'clean' command if you think somethign is corrupt

Answer (score 2):

Delete entire shadow build directory if you are using shadow build (default build setting is shadow build), then launch QtCreator and try to build.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger has probably put a lock on the file/directory that has not been released due to the power failure. 
Try to remove the Debug folder or use a tool (like this [one](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/)) to unlock the directory.