# Haskell linker unable to open output file

Tags: haskell, linker-errors, cabal

I am new to Haskell and I am using cabal for a small project. The project is managed on github and it works fine if I run `cabal run` on the current code. There are also no errors if I enter `ghci *.hs` However, if I make any changes to the code at all, the following is printed to the terminal. What might be the issue here?

```
C:\Users\65963\scripting-hs> cabal run       
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.3 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - scripting-hs-0.1.0.0 (exe:scripting-hs) (configuration changed)
Configuring executable 'scripting-hs' for scripting-hs-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing executable 'scripting-hs' for scripting-hs-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'scripting-hs' for scripting-hs-0.1.0.0..
Linking C:\Users\65963\scripting-hs\dist-newstyle\build\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.3\scripting-hs-0.1.0.0\x\scripting-hs\build\scripting-hs\scripting-hs.exe ...
C://ProgramData//chocolatey//lib//ghc//tools//ghc-8.10.3//mingw//bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file C:\Users\65963\CS Projects\St Andrews CS\CS2006\CS2006-Haskell2\scripting-hs\dist-newstyle\build\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.10.3\scripting-hs-0.1.0.0\x\scripting-hs\build\scripting-hs\scripting-hs.exe: Invalid argument
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
`gcc.exe' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Comment: One thing to try would be deleting the `dist-newstyle` subdirectory (which is generated by cabal, so you won't lose anything by doing that) and trying again. (N.B.: This is an educated guess based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605897/2751851), which reports a similar-looking issue when using the otherwise unrelated Qt toolchain.)

Comment: Not really sure if this is the problem here, but sometimes on Windows the toolchain fails to work with long file paths. As an experiment, you could try renaming "scripting-hs" to something shorter like "sc".